# SQL Decimal Confusion

Tags: sql

Could someone help me clear up some confusion...

I want to put in some decimal values into SQL Server. These decimals can be from 0.0001 to 1.9999

Do I set my data type to:

`Decimal(1,4)` meaning 1 digit before the point and 4 after

or

`Decimal(5,4)` meaning 5 total digits with 4 digits after the point.

Thanks!

Comment: Come on. You can google that very easy.

Comment: Easy for you to test isn't it? If you had done so you would have seen `Decimal(1,4)` is not a valid datatype. `The scale must be less than or equal to the precision.`

Comment: Why google when you have StackOverflow's Mechanical Turk to find your answers for you?

Comment: This has a direct answer [in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx "decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)"). I suggest you learn working with manuals before asking trivial questions.

Comment: @Will `will` you please google it for `decimal mysql`.

Comment: @Will: There's a (faint) hope that the time invested in teaching a person to first try available resources for simple answers will pay in the form of fewer trivial questions in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Decimal(5,4)` would be 5 total digits and 4 digits after the point

See this article for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832(v=sql.80).aspx

> p (precision)
>
> Specifies the maximum total number of decimal digits that can be
>   stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The
>   precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision. The
>   maximum precision is 38. The default precision is 18.
>
> s (scale)
>
> Specifies the maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to
>   the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through
>   p. Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default
>   scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based
>   on the precision.

Comment: Thanks Curt. My dyslexic brain and those MSDN pages dont mix well. Thanks for your answer to my what might seem easy to google question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,4),1.9999)
```

Comment: How did you post this 5 minutes after the question was closed?

Comment: [Ah right, answered here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/145673). Didn't realise that.

Comment: Sorry, I've been checking the condition in my server....